# CMake compile C++ file in custom command

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to precompile a header file in GCC with the following command:

```
ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
    OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/all.hpp.gch
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -o ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/all.hpp.gch ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/all.hpp
    DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/all.hpp
    COMMENT "Generating precompiled headers"
    )
```

However, I don't get CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS to expand into flags I've set using CMake's add_definitions(). What is the correct way of compiling in add_custom_command()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that `add_definitions()` adds its arguments to `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`. In fact, as far as I can tell they aren't saved anywhere (apart from arguments beginning with `-D` or `/D` which get added to `COMPILE_DEFINITIONS`).

The simplest way to solve that would be to, whenever calling `add_definitions()`, to also manually add those flags to `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`.

To see what is in `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` at any point, you can do

```
message(STATUS ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS})
```

or check the `CMakeCache.txt` in the build directory (or via `ccmake` or `cmake-gui`).